# Doctrine2 - FindOneBy foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

My problem is, that I have table movies_status, where I have two foreign keys: "movie", and "who". I'm trying to make DQL query, where I find single row by objects, id's of foreign keys, but it finds nothing.

Entity:

```
/**
 *
 * @var type 
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="movies")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="movie", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $movie;

/**
 *
 * @var type 
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="list_base")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="who", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $who;
```

Controller

```
/**
 * 
 * @Route("/introduction/updateTime", options={"expose"=true}, name="int_update_time")
 * @Method("post")
 */
public function updateTimeAction(Request $request) {

    $time = floor($request->request->get('time'));
    $movieUsId = $request->request->get('film_id');
    $userId = $request->request->get('id');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $movie = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:movies')->findOneBy(['useable_id' => $movieUsId]);
    $user = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:list_base')->findOneById($userId);

//here it finds nothing        
$moviesStatus = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:movies_status')->findOneBy(['who' => $user, 'movie' => $movie]);
        $currentTime = $moviesStatus->getFilmTime();

        $moviesStatus->setFilmTime($time);
        $em->persist($moviesStatus);
        $em->flush();

        if ($time == $currentTime) {
            return new Response("koniec");
        }

        return new Response("ok " . $time . " " . $userId . " " . $movieUsId . " " . $movie->getId() . " " . $user->getFirstName());
    }
```

Error is always:

```
Call to a member function getFilmTime() on null
```

In controller i also tried searching by ID, but still nothing.
I also tried to created custom query in repository:

```
 public function findOneMS($user, $movie) {

    $q = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('SELECT u FROM MainBundle:movies_status u WHERE u.who = :userId AND u.movie = :movieId')
            ->setParameter('userId', $user)
            ->setParameter('movieId', $movie)
            ->getSingleResult();
    return $q;
}
```

And yes, row exists in the database.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with: `$moviesStatus = $em->getRepository('MainBundle:movies_status')->findOneBy(['who' => $user->getId(), 'movie' => $movie->getId()]);` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Still got error `Call to a member function getFilmTime() on null`

Comment: check with the profiler if the query is fine and if data exists with there conditions

Comment: Query seems fine: `SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.film_time AS film_time_2, t0.open_date AS open_date_3, t0.movie AS movie_4, t0.who AS who_5 FROM movies_status t0 WHERE t0.who = ? AND t0.movie = ? LIMIT 1

Parameters: [0 => 35, 1 => 3] `

Comment: Maybe searching by Id is a wrong way here?

Answer (score 0):

Your two many-to-many relations have created two additional tables, which you should use in your request.

The query should look like this:

```
SELECT s.id FROM movies_status s, movies_status_movies m, movies_status_list_base u WHERE s.id = m.movies_status_id AND s.id = u.movies_status_id AND m.movie_id = :movieId AND u.list_base_id = :userId
```

Then load your Entity by returned id.